# How my user know about my update in android

Tags: android

I have a Android app and that is installed by my user now if i updated my app with newer versionCode changes in Manifest file so it is possible that Android market automatically notify my app user about my updated app or i have to write a code for this notify for my app user.

Comment: Taken care by Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

The Play Store automatically notifies the users about new updates of their Play Store apps.

Comment: ok thanks @jong but if i want to notify the user through code then what i have to do .

Comment: @Sahil, there is an hidden requirement that you're not telling us. First tell us why the Google Play notification system is not good enough for you, then we may be able to give you a better answer. But until you tell us why it won't work for you, we can't really help you very much. Our own suggestions may be wrong for the exact same reasons that the Google Play solution may already be wrong for you.

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk actually i have app with lots of images but now i have change that images in my project so for that i think version change is not good.

Comment: So basically, you want to be able to update the images, not necessarily the app?

Comment: @Sahil you have to integrate web service in your project and check for updates from your server manually.

Comment: Then try https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader or http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: is there any other way through code rather then implementing the web service @amalBit